# User search in RESTful spring API

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, search, restful-architecture, hibernate-search

So basically, I have a spring API with MySQL database and I need to be able to perform search of a user by his name in front-end web app which is using my API. The trick is that I need a kind of google search so by typing, lets say, 3 letters, list of all users who's name starts from these 3 letters would be returned from the API to the web app. By typing or deleting any letter, list should change dynamically.

My question is how can implement this kind of "dynamic" search in my API. What should requests look like? What should the whole architecture of the process in the API look like?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to pull this off.  Coding this in your API is probably going to be the least efficient.  I would recommend using SOLR or Lucene to index the data you want to search on.  Your front-end will have some JS that will update your list when characters are entered or deleted in the text field.

JQuery provides a plugin that might be just what you're looking for from the UI.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out.